# How to store altitude into Google Encoded Polyline Algorithm Format

Tags: google-maps, google-polyline, altitude

I am now working on creating route paths from multiple markers on Google Map by using the [Encoded Polyline Algorithm Format](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm?csw=1) where it encodes all the information of latitudes and longitudes into an encoded string.

For example, here are the points ( longitude, latitude );

> Points: (38.5, -120.2), (40.7, -120.95), (43.252, -126.453)

will become

> Encoded polyline: _p~iF~ps|U_ulLnnqC_mqNvxq`@

So my question is, are there any way I can insert additional data, for example ALTITUDE, inside the google polyline algorithm? Like points ( longitude, latitude, atitude, ...)? Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The question is can we add also more data then long,lat such as altitude - for example Points: (38.5, -120.2, 5.5), (40.7, -120.95, 5.6), (43.252, -126.453, 5.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.  Encoded polylines/polygons compress the latitude and longitude information into a more compact form, no additional information can be added.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try other way to store the altitude